# Insert Keyframe reverses Mirror option?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I rotate both arms using the Mirror option, then I press "Insert Keyframe" -> "All Channels".

One arm snaps back to the previous position.
It seems to me that Blender ignores the "Mirror" option and only keyframes the one arm which I have actually rotated instead of both.

Am I right?

I have recorded a video of this strange behaviour [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KERh9oWrivA).

Can anybody help?

[image]

[image]

Edit: I have filed a [bug report here](https://developer.blender.org/T83451) because it seems so strange.
If I select both bones (left and right bone) manually and rotate, it persists, so I'm really baffled what goes on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Insert Keyframe* will only create keyframes for the selected bone(s), not for all the bones of your armature. You've only selected one bone in your video, the mirrored bone will also move because of the X mirror option, but it won't be taken into account as it is not selected.

*All Channels* means that it will create keyframes for all the channels of this bone (*Location, Rotation* and *Scale*).

If you want the rotation to be taken account for all your bones, activate the *Auto Keying* option, but in that case you don't need to insert a keyframe.

Also, try to not report a bug if you're not sure it's a bug.